# Can not upload images to a rails website, any comment for me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie and trying to make a very simple rails website. I am trying to upload a photo to this website, and here is my code

`<div class="col m4 center">
<%= image_tag "/assets/images/courses/4.jpg", class: "img-responsive"%>
</div>`

The photo's folder is ofcourse named `courses` and in `/assets/images/`

I thought that this is ok, but my problem is, when I check my website, the photo could not loading.
It liked this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akvmk.jpg.)

I am very confusing because I tried to change many photos, type, and folder, but nothing changed.

Could you please give me some ideas?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

When you put an image inside /assets/images, Rails will use Sprockets to compile it and it modifies it's name with a digest hash. Instead of using the complete path, just use the part inside /images, that way rails will know what to do:

```
image_tag 'courses/4.jpg', class: 'img-responsive'
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag check the examples

Comment: Thank you very much, by reading your comment now I can upload my photos.